# Can't extract the dictionary as [String : Any] from vapor request context

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm new to server side swift. I'm using vapor for server side swift. In vapor request I need to get JSON as [String: Any] to check a data type of the value like String, Int or Float. But in request the I can't find the exact data type of the value.

```
drop.post("post") { (request) -> ResponseRepresentable in
     guard let name = request.data["value"]?.string else {
        throw Abort.badRequest
     }
     return value
}
```

In above method, it directly converts and returns the value as String. I need to check it is a String or Int (some other data types too). I can't check by let condition which is given as below.

```
guard let name = data["value"] as? String else {
    \\do something
}
```

I need to check it is a String or Int (some other data types too). If anyone has the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to get Type of data using a type(of:) function, in result you will get optional any like this.

```
let dic = ["key":"string"] as [String : Any]

let str = dic["key"] //"string"

type(of: str) //Optional<Any>.Type
```

you have to check with " if let " for all case.

```
let dic = ["key":"string"] as [String : Any]

if let str = dic["key"] as? String {
   print("String value")

} else if let intvalue = dic["key"] as? Int {
    print("Int value")

} else if let boolvalue = dic["key"] as? Bool {
   print("Bool value")

}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: No. It convert if i gave body["key"]?.String as String. Otherwise it type was "Node".

Comment: if you dont know they type of object then it's not work, you have to use "if let"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're accessing the JSON, I'd do it like this.

```
guard let json = request.json else {
    throw ...
}

if let string = json.string {
    // JSON is a string
} else if let object = json.object {
    // JSON is a [String: JSON] 
}

// continue unwrapping for different data types
```

I wouldn't recommend using the `type(of:)` function for this purpose.